# Entity Framework Core: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database with a hierarchy of categories. Each category has a parentcategoryid. I call the following function to load the top level categories and then it recursively calls itself to load all the children.

However, I get the following error:

> SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other
>   threads running in the session.

```
    public async Task LoadCategoriesAsync()
    {
        await LoadCategoriesByParentId(null);
    }

    private async Task LoadCategoriesByParentId(int? sourceParentId, int? parentId)
    {
        var sourceCategories = _dbContext.SourceCategory.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == sourceParentId);
        foreach (var sourceCategory in sourceCategories)
        {
            var newCategory = new Category()
            {
                Name = sourceCategory.Name,
                Description = sourceCategory.Description,
                ParentCategoryId = parentId
            };

            _dbContext.Category.Add(newCategory);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            //category.EntityId = newCategory.Id;
            //_dbContext.SourceCategory.Update(category);
            //await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            await LoadCategoriesByParentId(sourceCategory.CategoryId, newCategory.Id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Where()` statement doesn't retrieve the data; just "opens the cursor" (in old-speak). So, you can't do `SaveChange()`. The simplest solution is to convert `IEnumerable` to `List` or `Array`:

```
var rootCategories = _dbContext.SourceCategory.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == parentId).ToList();
```

But I would strongly recommend you google the error and understand why it is happening. To do this recursively is **begging** for trouble

Comment: Thanks. The ToList() works, but I see what you mean. If I put breakpoints and stop at each time my method is called, I get all the data, but if I let it run without breakpoints, I only get partial data. However, I don't see any other way to do what I am trying to do. Because it is a hierarchy and I need to know the parentID of each item I insert, I need to start at the top and work my way down recursively. Do you know of any other approach I can try?

Comment: For starters, it's not clear what you *want* to do. You don't assign the categories; so they are lost at the end of the call.

Comment: I had an error in my code above, passing in the wrong ParentId. I just changed the code above. It seems to work when I add ToList() now but it is very slow. I have one table with a hierarchy of categories and I am inserting them into another table.